# How to pass initialization data to angular module?

Tags: angularjs

I have a webmethod on my remote server returning a JSon object.
Said json object contains strings which are required for the module to proper work.

So, is there a way to pass something to an angular module?
An idea could be to perform an http request inside of the initialization of the module:

```
$scope.init = function(){
        $http.get ()
            ...
         then(){
               $scope.mydata = result;
         }

};
```

But that would be asynchronous...

Comment: why not pass a service. that can provide you with that end point?

Comment: mmm...an example of that?

Comment: I'm doing exactly that to initialize [schemaform.io](http://schemaform.io) form definition and schema JSONobjects. If you are using a third party module you can trigger an event to reinitialize on your $http.get() success or if it's your own module, create a function that will reinitialize the module with the new data.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about the async nature of an HTTP request to fill out your $scope.mydata variable, then you need to include this in a RESOLVE in your route.

I'm using UI-ROUTER in my current project:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('capps.core')
        .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

            $stateProvider
                .state('home.capps', {
                    url: '/',
                    template: '<ui-view/>',
                    data: {
                        requireLogin: true
                    },
                    resolve:{
                        resolveFunction: resolveFunction
                    }
                });
        }
    ]);

    resolveFunction['$inject'] = ['$http'];
    function resolveFunction($http) {
        return $http.get(API_URL)
                .then(function(res) {
                    console.log(res);
                });
    }
})();
```

Then in your controller, you can pass 'resolveFunction' as a dependency... then use that to assign to your $scope.myData.

```
...
angular.controller('myController', myController);

myController.$inject = ['resolveFunction', '$scope'];
function myController(resolveFunction, $scope) {
    $scope.mydata = resolveFunction.data;
    console.log(mydata);
};
```

Comment: There are other ways of doing this like Suda said... personally I would contain all of the REST interaction inside a service.  Then within the resolve I would call a loadMyData() function to GET the data from the API... then in the controller you know the data is already initialized in the service.  So you can set ...

$scope.myData = myDataService.getMyData();  (this is not an API call but a reference to the singleton service that contains the data it already pulled from the API).